# How to create a custom attribute for Code-first model class?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Environment:ASP.NET MVC5 + entity framework code first

I have a question about to define a custom attribute for Code-fist class.

```
public class Vender
{
    public int VenderID { get; set; }
    public string VenderCode { get; set; }
    public string CompanyCode { get; set; }

    public string CompanyFullName { get; set; }

    public string CreateUser { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "City")]
    public int VenderCityId { get; set; }

}
```

Then I have a City class. This Datatable will store lots of cities

```
public class City
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Another table for DataAuditLog

```
public class DataAudit
{
    public enum DbActionType
    {
        [Display(Name = "Add")] I,
        [Display(Name = "Update")] U,
        [Display(Name = "Delete")] D
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string TableName { get; set; }

    public string TableDataId { get; set; }

    public string UserId { get; set; }

    public DbActionType DbAction { get; set; }

    public string PropertyName { get; set; }
    public string OldData { get; set; }

    public string NewData { get; set; }

    public DateTime UpdateDateTime { get; set; }
}
```

I use this table to log all the changes in Vender table. So there are table name, id and property to locate the specific line of Vender

So here is my intend to do.

1.create a custom attribute for

```
[Display(Name = "City")]
[CustomAttribute(City)]
public int VenderCityId { get; set; }
```

2.in viewmodel, get this custom attribute and query the name for the city for display.

My question is
1. Is it a good design? If not, please advise me
2. If yes, I do not find how to custom a attribute for the property.

Edit：
add the view. Current design, the data log for city likes OldData="1" , NewData="2"， which extract from DB.
I just to show the value to OldData="Shanghai" , NewData="Beijing"

```
<div>
<table class="table">
    <tr>

        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DataAuditsList.FirstOrDefault().UserId)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DataAuditsList.FirstOrDefault().PropertyName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DataAuditsList.FirstOrDefault().DbAction)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DataAuditsList.FirstOrDefault().OldData)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DataAuditsList.FirstOrDefault().NewData)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DataAuditsList.FirstOrDefault().UpdateDateTime)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model.DataAuditsList)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserId)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PropertyName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DbAction)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OldData)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NewData)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UpdateDateTime)
            </td>

        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to inherit a class from "ValidationAttiribute" like this:

```
public class CustomAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{

}
```

And then do what you want in your class... you can override isValid method for validation logic

```
Edit:

      <td>
          //You can send a query to db right here, receive city name for "item.OldData" and show it in label 
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OldData)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NewData)
        </td>
```

or as i said before you can do this in your controller of this view.but i thought you want just display one record,if you want more you can use Dictionary for it, 'key' is the OldData and the value is the city name,then you can put this dictionary in your ViewBag,but you have already have DataAuditsList,can you add two more property to it? OldName and NewName and set these property values in your controller then in your view just change this lines

```
   <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OldName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NewName)
        </td>
```

---

Last Edit:

You can define a static class and some helper methods:

```
private static YourDBContext ctx = new YourDbContext();

public static class HelperMethods {
public static string GetCityName(string cityId){ //your olddata is string
string name = (from c in ctx.City
                where c.Id == cityId
                 select c.Name);

return name;
}
```

}

Then you can calls this method from your view:

```
    <td>
        @HelperMethods.GetCityName(item.OldData)
    </td>
    <td>
        @HelperMethods.GetCityName(item.NewData)
    </td>
```

In fact you can define extension methods,just put 'this' keyword before your cityId parameter:

```
public static string GetCityName(this string cityId)
```

And then call it like this:

```
@item.OldData.GetCityName()
```

If you want to extend this functionality,you can define many other methods,and it will be a better common way i think.Good luck...

Comment: Actually, I do not want to do the validation, is it OK?

Comment: i understand but i don't understand where do you want to display your city name exactly?

Comment: if you want to display it in VenderCityId's place then it's a bad design.You can do it in your controller,receive your city name from DB and then show it in your view.you can use ViewBag for this for example in your controller:

ViewBag.CityName = cityname; //this comes from db
return View(VenderModel);

And in your view 

var cityName = ViewBag.CityName;

@Html.DisplayFor(model=>model.VenderCityId)
<input type="text" value=@cityName />

i don't know how is your view but i hope you understand what i mean

Comment: I just add my view in the post

Comment: I will plenty of class like city,so I need a common way,that's why I want to use attribute

Comment: i understood but i still think attributes doesn't appropriate way for this.i edit my message for last time i hope this helps.